# Does Instagram APIs support batch calls?

Tags: batch-processing, instagram-api

I have to make two api calls to get the follower-counts. So, with the rate of 5000 per hour, I can get 2500 follower-counts per hour!
So, to get 20000 follower-counts takes around 10 hours. Both, Facebook and Twitter APIs support batch calls. So, I was wondering whether Instagram supports batch calls as well?
Looking at the instagram documentation, I do not see any notion of batching!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

the limitations are separate for authenticated requests and unauthenticated requests. For authenticated requests, the limits are *per user* so if you have 20 users registered with your app you multiply that by 20 and so on.

https://instagram.com/developer/limits/